# Is there a way to efficiently convert the data type in a DataFrame's column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A DataFrame `df` has a column named `LastPrice`. Each of `df['LastPrice']` is a `string`, I want to convert `string` to `float`. I use `map` to solve it.

```
#-*- encoding:utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'Time':['1-14','1-15','1-16'],'LastPrice':['1.0','2.0','3.0']},columns = ['Time','LastPrice'])
f_L = df['LastPrice'].map(float)
print type(f_L[0])
print type(df['LastPrice'][0])
```

The result is:

```
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'str'>
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

So `map` can't convert data types in-placce, I just do:

```
df['LastPrice'] = f_L
```

Is there a way to covert the data type in a DataFrame's column efficiently? 
What I mean is coverting data type in-place, instead of reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for `pandas` version >= `0.17.0`:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['LastPrice'])

In [110]: pd.to_numeric(df['LastPrice'])
Out[110]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: LastPrice, dtype: float64
```

In versions <= `0.17.0` you could use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html):

```
In [112]: df['LastPrice'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[112]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: LastPrice, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['LastPrice'] = df['LastPrice'].astype(float)


df = DataFrame({'Time':['1-14','1-15','1-16'],'LastPrice':['1.0','2.0','3.0']},
                                                              columns = ['Time','LastPrice'])

df['LastPrice'] = df['LastPrice'].astype(float)
print df
   Time  LastPrice
0  1-14          1
1  1-15          2
2  1-16          3

print type(df['LastPrice'][0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use a custom Function

```
def str_to_flt(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Then I use the custom function by

```
 df['FloatField']=df['StrField'].apply(str_to_flt)
```

I can then identify the "bad" values as they are set to NaN.

Hope this helps.